Android tests are getting crashed when trying to run
I have been trying to run test on my macbook pro m1. The espresso test is running fine on my colleagues laptop with same configuration.
SDK is set to 34 and I'm using Pixel 7 API 34 for my testing.
Initially the test was working fine but since yesterday it started crashing
here is the log
> Task :qa-automation:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 0 tests on Pixel_7_API_34(AVD) - 14

Finished 0 tests on Pixel_7_API_34(AVD) - 14

> Task :qa-automation:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Test run failed to complete. No test results

FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':qa-automation:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
 
Get more help at 
https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED
 in 12s

216 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 207 up-to-date

Log cat device log
.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator
2024-09-17 17:50:30.986 10630-10630 DEBUG                   pid-10630                            A  Cmdline: app_process / androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -w -r --no-window-animation -e clearPackageData true -e class veeva.vault.mobile.qaautomation.test.dashboard.DashboardTest#dashboardSortFilterTest -e additionalTestOutputDir /sdcard/Android/media/com.veeva.vault.mobile.debug/additional_test_output -e testTimeoutSeconds 31536000 -e targetInstrumentation veeva.vault.mobile.qaautomation.test/veeva.vault.mobile.qaautomation.testutil.QaAutomationRunner androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator


reinstall android studio
clone new repo
reset and format laptop
checked on my colleagues laptop and it is working fine


Your question is missing the actual error message from the build process. Instead of starting the tests please just start the build process and include the output, formatted as code in three backticks into your question.
